# Does proget support OData queries for Tags?

Tags: nuget-server, proget

I am trying to query a proget server using the Nuget.Core API. This method:

```
using System.IO.Packaging;
public IEnumerable<IPackage> GetAllProgramPackages(string feedUrl)
{
    var repository = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(feedUrl);            
    var query = repository.GetPackages();            
    var programPackages = query.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains("ClientPackage"));    
    return programPackages;

}
```

Should, as I understands it, return only packages where Tags contains "ClientPackage".
It actually returns the entire repository, which is not desirable.  I could always filter client-side after the query returns, but with a couple of thousand nuget packages in our repository, it wouldn't be a good option.

Is it possible to run a OData query for tags against a proget server, and have it executed server-side?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can filter any property on a `substringof` match (similar to `Contains()` in C#).  Just use:

```
http://proget/nuget/Default/Packages()?$filter=substringof(tags,'ClientPackage')
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I see when I hook up Fiddler and run the method described in the initial post.  Problem is, I get all the packages in my repository in return, which is not what I want.  Hence the question, it seems like this either is a bug in proget or not supported?

Comment: What version of ProGet are you using? When I ran this query on the latest version (v3.1.6 at the time) I only saw the packages that contained the specified substring.

Comment: Not sure which version, but it's fairly recent.  Fileversion on progetcore.dll says 3.1.0.8.  I did manage to get around my problem by using an equal comparer instead of contains, like this:
    var programPackages = query.Where(p => p == "ClientPackage");